# very short probability question help?

Tags: probability

We have the table in the figure.We have the distribution of $X$ and $Y$.It doesnt say in my book if $X$ and $Y$ are indipendent or not.This exercise had many many questions but there were two which I couldnt find.

I have to find $K = P(x=2,y=-1)$ and $F(X)$

I have no idea how to find the first one,I even thought that the sum of the first row should be 1,which obviously is wrong,then I tried to do smth related to $P(x=2\mid y=-1)$ but still...

as for the second,I know how to find $F(X)$ if we have an $X$, not two $X$'s ($2$ and $4$ in the figure)..HELP :/

The table :

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
X\backslash Y&-3&-1&1\\ \hline
2&0.2&K&0.3\\ \hline
4&0.05&0.15&0\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG4R7.jpg).

Comment: Another very short hint: $P(Y=-3)=0.25$.

Comment: Hint: The table tells you the probability of the _intersection_ of the events $P\{X = i\}$ and $P\{Y = j\}$. For example, the probability that $X$ equals $2$ and _simultaneously_ $Y$ equals $-3$ is $0.2$. You also need to understand that $X$ and $Y$ cannot take on any values other than those shown in the margins (first column and first row). Finally, the second axiom of probability theory asserts that $P(\Omega) = 1$. Can you figure out the value of $K$ from this?

Comment: If I knew what $F(X)$ was intended to mean, maybe I could find it. But note that $\Pr(X=4)=0.05+0.15+0=0.2$, so $\Pr(X=2)=0.8$. Now we know the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Andre,thanks,so K=0.3.F(X) is the density of the probabilities of X.

Answer (score 2):

Very short hint: [Second and third axioms of probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Second_axiom)

Comment: Very short answer :Thanks.